# Get subitem value in radlistview items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, telerik, rad-controls

here is my listview

```
<telerik:RadListView runat="server" ID="lvAllUsers" Width="30px">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td >
          <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbID" runat="server" CssClass="item" Font-Size="15px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="    "  > </asp:ListItem>
          </asp:CheckBoxList></td>
          <td style="padding-bottom:10px"><%# Eval("FirstName") %></td>
          <td style="padding-bottom:10px"><%# Eval("FamilyName") %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:RadListView>
```

how can I get checkboxlists item text at code behind ? or how can I get FirstName and FamilyName and code behind after I binded my data at pageload? 
I can't use

```
 foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.RadListViewItem item in lvAllUsers.Items) {
   var cb = item.FindControl(index);
 }
```

because index is equals an id normally. But in item template id is not equal to cbID. When item template iteratives, id is changing. I need get FirstName and FamilyName or checkboxlists item at codebehind (c# only not js). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. It's seems like a little long way but it works.

```
foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.RadListViewItem item in lvAllUsers.Items)
{
    if (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList)(((System.Web.UI.Control)(item)).Controls[1])).Items[0].Selected)
    {
        ccUserNames.Add(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)(((System.Web.UI.Control)(item)).Controls[7])).Text);
    }
}
```